# делал парсер озон,блокает антибот.прочитал,что можно воспользоваться undetectedchromedriver,но не понял как. как работать с ним или какие альтернативы

Tags: парсер

код на селениум. видел, что еще можно воспользоваться прокси для обхода антибота. браузер установлен хром в селениуме. все сделано на питоне. https://github.com/korovokliu/ozon-wildberries-parser - ссылка на код, который у меня не работает как я думаю как раз изза антибота. вот эго и пытаюсь заставить заработать. помогите. что нужно добавить или изменить в коде?